# Php date function giving back incorrect week number

Tags: php, date, week-number

I have an issue with the php date function when getting the week it is incrementing it by 1.

For example:

2020-11-31 is becoming week 49 instead of week 48.

Code as follows:

```
date("W",strtotime("2020-11-30"));
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all November has 30 days, not 31. 2nd, if you pass the correct date 2020-11-30 then this IS 49th week indeed.
Week Number:49/2020
Start Date: Nov 29, 2020
End Date: Dec 5, 2020

You can also do this:

```
$ddate = "2020-11-30";
$date = new DateTime($ddate);
$week = $date->format("W");
echo "Week Number: $week";
```

Comment: Sorry had a mistake i meant the 30th but as you can see 2020-11-30 falls under week 48 not 49

Comment: Week 49 starts 30/11 and ends 6/12 in 2020

Comment: How do you figure? https://whatweekisit.com shows it as week 49, as does https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2020

Comment: From what I can see here: https://www.timeanddate.com/date/weeknumber.html 
and here https://www.calendar-365.com/week-number.html  OR pull up your excel and type in the date in the column A2, then in another column do =WEEKNUM(A2), it will show you date week num as 49. Again PHP returns the correct week num.

Comment: @MatthewScicluna _as you can see_ ...see where, exactly? All the links provided show the opposite. Do you have an alternative source of information? Some alternative facts from alternative universe, perhaps?